# Disable the KendoReact Calendar Fast Navigation Bar globally

Tags: kendo-react-ui

The KendoReact Calendar Fast Navigation Bar is currently broken in all versions of KendoReact that support React 18 as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/1566).

We are working around the issue by [disabling the Calendar Fast Navigation Bar](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/calendar/sidebar/). This is a suitable workaround for simple isolated components such as DatePickers, but unfortunately does nothing to address the issue in for example KendoReact Grid filter menus. See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-va2kr1?file=app%2Fmain.tsx) for a working example of the issue.

Is there a way to globally disable the Calendar Fast Navigation Bar so we don't have to apply this everywhere and create custom Grid filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `CalendarPropsContext` [as described here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/props-context/).

e.g.

```js
const calendarProps = React.useCallback(
    (calendarProps: CalendarProps) => ({
      ...calendarProps,
      navigation: false,      
    }),
    []
  );

return (
    <CalendarPropsContext.Provider value={calendarProps}>
      ...
    </CalendarPropsContext.Provider>
  );
```